# Is there a brushless motor controller accepting over 500 updates/s?

Tags: brushless-motor, esc, line-following

I want to use brushless for my line follower.
The problem is most ESCs don't accept more than 400-500 updates/s due to the characteristic of steering signal.
Is there a way to overcome this with a custom flash or am I out of luck?

Comment: Under what circumstances is a >500 updates/second rate needed for line following? How many km/hr do you anticipate the line follower moving?

Comment: Under any competion-winning ones. It has to move at least 4m/s at times.

Answer (score 1):

The thing i was looking for turned out to be the KISS ESC:
http://flyduino.net/KISS-ESC-2-4S-18A-v11_1

It has an update speed of op to 2000Hz due to it's own control method called oneshot125.

Comment: There is some discussion here; http://www.multiwii.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=1947&start=650  Many conclude it is marketing hype. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some off the shelf ESCs which claim to give 400Hz + update rate

1000Hz
http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__39708__Afro_ESC_30Amp_Multi_rotor_Motor_Speed_Controller_SimonK_Firmware_.html

600Hz 
http://www.amain.com/next-level-30-amp-multi-rotor-esc-w-simonk-firmware/p265104

499Hz
http://www.helipal.com/storm-multirotor-30a-opto-esc.html

Normally SimonK firmware should give you some scope to play around for your requirements. You can refer following links

https://github.com/sim-/tgy

http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1513678